# The parameters in TLS1.2 server signature with ECDSA

Tags: tls

I'm trying to write a webserver.
I'm using TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1).
I generated a CA certificate using OpenSSL (using prime256v1).
I generated the hash using server_random + client_random + curve_info + temp_publickey (just binary connect).
But when I test, OpenSSL returns them:

```
read from 0x5898a1fa42f0 [0x5898a1fbe4b3] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
0000 - 16 03 03 00 6c                                    ....l
read from 0x5898a1fa42f0 [0x5898a1fbe4b8] (108 bytes => 108 (0x6C))
0000 - 0c 00 00 68 03 00 1d 20-be 51 3d 23 dd 6c d7 68   ...h... .Q=#.l.h
0010 - 70 c5 85 7f a8 7b 3e 46-d6 83 c5 3d 86 f0 10 1e   p....{>F...=....
0020 - 4b 8c 5f ac 50 5a de 06-04 03 00 40 c1 a2 8d bb   K._.PZ.....@....
0030 - 3b 55 41 2f d1 e9 04 0e-e8 ef 80 ca e2 f9 3d c9   ;UA/..........=.
0040 - 02 b4 43 96 e2 e4 fb 88-a9 28 58 0d 13 86 b1 09   ..C......(X.....
0050 - 2e 8a 86 39 7c 26 5a fb-b4 a1 7e 5c d1 1a 43 4c   ...9|&Z...~\..CL
0060 - 8f 48 02 59 13 4b 5e 64-9b f3 4d 68               .H.Y.K^d..Mh
write to 0x5898a1fa42f0 [0x5898a1fb9220] (7 bytes => 7 (0x7))
0000 - 15 03 03 00 02 02 33                              ......3
40976155FB740000:error:0A00007B:SSL routines:tls_process_key_exchange:bad signature:ssl/statem/statem_clnt.c:2529:
```

Did I do something wrong?
My program part:

```
                    let (_temp_private_key, temp_public_key) = get_tls_keys();
                    let sign = unsafe {
                        let mut ca_private_key = SSL_PRIVATE_KEY.get();

                        let mut origin_data = client_msg.random.bytes().to_vec();
                        origin_data.extend(serverhello_random.bytes());
                        origin_data.extend([0x03, 0x00, 0x1d]); // X25519
                        origin_data.extend(temp_public_key.clone());
                        let mut data = sha256::Sha256::digest(&origin_data);
                        let mut sign = [0; 64];
                        ecdsa_sign(ca_private_key.as_mut_ptr(), data.as_mut_ptr(), sign.as_mut_ptr());
                        sign.to_vec()
                    };

                    let serverkeyexchange = HandshakeMessage {
                        handshake_content: HandshakeContent::ServerKeyExchange(
                            HandshakeServerKeyExchange {
                                curve_name: crate::https::tls::CurveName::X25519,
                                public_key: temp_public_key,
                                sign,
                            },
                        ),
                        length: 0,
                    }
```

`get_tls_keys` return random public key and private key.

Comment: It looks like you're computing the signature over the correct data, but for ECDSA (not EdDSA) the signature (within the TLS 'opaque' field) **should be encoded as ASN.1 DER sequence** -- see https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8422#page-19 -- not simply the flat values of R and S as in some other standards like PKCS11 xmldsig JWS and part of Bitcoin